# Why is using abstract class better for inheritance than using normal class?

Tags: java, inheritance

Consider this sample code where I have used normal class to implement generalized concept first and then using subclasses to specialize:

```
package check;
class figure{
  void area(){
  System.out.println("\n Superclass for any figure"); //An useless print statement
  }
}

class triangle extends figure{
  void area()
  {
    System.out.println("\n Code to determine area of a triangle");
  }
}
```

For the same implementation using abstract class, the code would be:

```
abstract class figure1{
  abstract void area();
}

class triangle1 extends figure1{
  void area()
  {
    System.out.println("\n Code to determine area of a triangle");
  }
}
```

Now reading my textbook in JAVA (Herbert Schildt, Complete Reference, 7th edition) it appeared to me that the writer wants to convey that somehow using abstract class is better in case of generalization-specialization approaches. However, I failed to understand how it is better than using normal class. Using abstract class essentially enforces us to extend the base class and that's all; other than that I am unable to see any huge difference in the implementation. So can anybody make me understand how using abstract class is a better practice/approach than using normal class?

Comment: **Unrelated**. Class names in Java by convention should start with an upper case letter. Read this: [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Comment: @informatik01, Yeah! I know! I just typed the code in the SO editor fast, so didn't bother to look. Anyway thanks for mentioning.

Comment: The title is a little bit loaded. Maybe it should be "When are abstract classes better for inheritance"

Comment: your assumption is wrong, *its not*. Also this is not a discussion forum, this is not on-topic!

Comment: @JarrodRoberson, Why do you think it is generating discussion? I am seeing answers quite objectively pointing out the differences between them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An abstract class can never be instantiated and this is the real advantage of the abstract class.

For example, the class `Animal` could be an abstract class; but in real life you can never have an instance of an `Animal`; that makes no sense at all as you can't just create an Animal, you create ***an*** Animal, such as a `Cat` or `Dog` in real life as they are real-world entities. So in terms of the translation between the code design and the real-world concept or situation, abstract classes are much better as they can provide a much neater portrayal of the real-world situation.

Comment: Good explanation on abstraction. One vote from mine

Comment: `but in real life you can never have an instance of an Animal; that makes no sense at all.` I have to nitpick. They absolutely are instances of Animal. I think the better wording would be, for ANY thing that is an animal, it is also something more specific, namely dog, cat etc...

Comment: yeah, but this is just code to do an application. Who cares If it doesnt make sense to have an instance of "Animal". If it does not make sense just dont do it. There is no point in make another version of the language just to implement "realism" into a coding tool.

Answer (score 8):

There is no "better" nor "worse", it depends on your purpose.

An abstract class allows declaring abstract methods that **need** to be implemented by the child class if the child class is not abstract itself.

A non-abstract does not, you need to implement all your declared methods.

Think of an abstract class as a "generic" object, that wouldn't exist as such in real life but provides a good generalization for a number of other concrete objects.

Think of the non-abstract class as something you could actually point your finger at in real life.

Answer (score 7):

Using an abstract method means that nobody can instantiate the class.

In other words, noone can create a Shape and then use that: they have to create something that extends shape, such as a Circle or a Rectangle.

Comment: Also in a abstract class, you can have abstract methods that dont need a function definition until a class implements it

Comment: this is fundamentally incorrect, you can create an anonymous instance of the class as long as you provide the implementation when you do so; this is no different than doing the same thing with an Interface.

Comment: In that case you've still extended the class, just anonymously.

Answer (score 1):

One more advantage to having abstract classes in addition to what others pointed out is you can add more sub-classes to it as need arise. Suppose you have `Shape` abstract class and `Circle` and `Triangle` `concrete` classes, in future if you've a need for `Polygon` you can easily add that.

Take `abstract` class as a high level entity and `concrete` class as a more `specialized` form of a `generic` entity with specialized class inheriting all the properties of generic class and defining its own behavior where it differs from generic class

Answer (score 0):

You might also look at Effective Java's directive about the `equals()` method.  It is tricky, if not downright impossible, to implement that method in a contract-respecting way when you have two concrete classes in an inheritance relationship.

Answer (score 0):

> Using abstract class essentially enforces us to extend the base class **and that's all**; other than that I am unsable to see any huge difference in the implementation. So can anybody make me understand how using abstract class is a better practice/approach than using normal class?

An abstract class serves the same purpose as an Interface -- it creates a functional contract that says if I have an instance of it, I know these methods will be available.  The additional benefit of an abstract class is that it can contain implementations of methods that subclasses will share without the need to implement said method in the subclasses.

```
 public abstract class AbstractFoo{
    public abstract void process(); // subclasses forced to implement
    public String getValue(Object b){
         String s = "Hi!!";
         // stuff happens....maybe
         return s;
 }

 public class ConcreteFoo extends AbstractFoo{
     public void process(){
         // you forced me to!! Oh well, I want to honor the contract
         // anyway
     }
 }

 public class Main{
     public static void main(String[] args){
        AbstractFoo f = new ConcreteFoo();
        System.out.println(f.getValue(new Object()));
     }
 }
```

This gives

```
 Hi!!
```

as the output.  Notice `ConcreteFoo` didn't have to implement `getValue`.

Comment: Right, sometimes I prefer abstract classes over interfaces, because changing the interface is a lot of work :)

Answer (score 0):

An abstract class is a class that is declared abstract—it may or may not include abstract methods. Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, but they can be subclassed. `Abstract classes` are most commonly subclassed to share pieces of implementation. A single abstract class is subclassed by similar classes that have a lot in common, which provides flexibility in OOP design. And we use this class for abstracting out the properties which are common among various type of Classes.

For example, Suppose we  circles, rectangles, lines graphics object which has lots in common about their states, for example: `position, orientation, line color, fill color`. However, If we define an `Abstract` class as:

```
abstract class GraphicObject {
    int x, y;
    Color color;

    abstract void draw();

}
```

Now, Each non-abstract subclass of `GraphicObject`, such as `Circle` and `Rectangle`, must provide implementations for the `draw` method, which may contain drawing code for specific location with specific color( i may want a circle to be drawn with color `red`, and a rectangle with color `green` with different location `(x,y)`):

```
class Circle extends GraphicObject {
    void draw() {
        ...
    }

}
class Rectangle extends GraphicObject {
    void draw() {
        ...
    }

}
```

One of the most powerful object-oriented techniques is subtype polymorphism, the ability to handle multiple specialized types from a single, `supertype` viewpoint.

Check out this article to understand in depth:

1. **[Reveal the magic behind subtype polymorphism](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2001/jw-0413-polymorph.html)**
2. **[Maximize flexibility with interfaces and abstract classes](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-09-2001/jw-0921-interface.html?page=1)**